# Multiprocessing in AWS Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to scan all the cloudwatch log groups(nearly 10k log groups) and check for subscription filters in my AWS Account.Since we have an lambda execution time restriction of 15 mins.I'm using Multiprocessing for this to complete it by 15 mins. Here is my code. When i execute this, its code is giving a timeout error

```
import time
import concurrent.futures
import boto3
from multiprocessing import Process, Pipe

logs = boto3.client('logs')

def describe_log_groups():
    paginator = logs.get_paginator('describe_log_groups')
    for page in paginator.paginate():
        for log_groups in page['logGroups']:
            yield(log_groups)

def describe_subscription_filter(loggroupname,conn):
    print('In Subscription Filters')
    response = logs.describe_subscription_filters(logGroupName=loggroupname)['subscriptionFilters']
    if len(response) != 0:
        for log in response:
            print(log['destinationArn'])
        conn.send([log['destinationArn']])
    conn.close()

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    t1 = time.perf_counter()
    evlaute_loggroups = []
    processes = []
    parent_connections = []
    loggroups_list = describe_log_groups()
    for loggroup in loggroups_list:
        parent_conn, child_conn = Pipe()
        parent_connections.append(parent_conn)
        print(parent_connections)
        print(loggroup['logGroupName'])
        process = Process(target=describe_subscription_filter, args=(loggroup['logGroupName'], child_conn,))
        processes.append(process)
        for process in processes:
            process.start()
        for process in processes:
            process.join()
        for parent_connection in parent_connections:
            print(parent_connection.recv()[0])
        print('done')



    t2 = time.perf_counter()
    print(f'Finished in {t2-t1} seconds')
```

I also have a doubt, using multiprocessing can we scan huge amount of log groups in Lambda.

Answer (score 1):

Using multiprocessing in lambda is not going to help much. The computational power of your function is related to its **RAM allocation**.

If you want your function to run faster, you have to give it more RAM. With **1792 MB** of RAM your function gets an allocation of **1 vCPU**. This means that even with max amount of RAM (3008 MB) you will not get 2 vCPUs. Since one 1vCP can be considered as equivalent to 1 hyper-thread on a physical CPU core, your lambda function is basically **limited to one thread**.

You can consider the following options:

- check execution time with more RAM,
- simplify your code. Instead of having one large function, have few smaller function which can be orchestrated using Step Functions for instance,
- move from lambda to other service, e.g. ECS.